# Make headwidth = paperwidth, regardless of page geometry

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like the headsepline of each page to extend across the page. The problem I am encountering is when the geometry is changed via `\newgeometry`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[headsepline, headwidth=paper:\the\textwidth/2-\the\paperwidth/2:\the\textwidth/2-\the\paperwidth/2]{scrlayer-scrpage}    

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

On the pages with new geometry, the header does not extend across the page. How can I make `scrlayer-scrpage` extend the headsepline with an arbitrary page geometry?

Comment: You really can't. You are using 2 competing methods to layout the header dimensions and they are always going to compete. When you say `\newgeometry`, *geometry* is in charge and `scrlayer-scrpage` knows nothing about it. Likewise, `geometry` knows nothing about anything you've told `scrlayer-scrpage`. You *can* use `geometry` with KOMA but (1) you lose some KOMA functionality; (2) you should then stick to `geometry` consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code the header offset is calculated once depending on the current `\textwidth`. It is not recalculated if the `\textwidth` is changed.

If the `headoffset` should depend on flexible `\textwidth` you have to ensure that the `headwidth` including the offsets is recalculated on every page.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{onpsbackground={\KOMAoptions{headwidth=paper}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}\KOMAoptions{headwidth=paper}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, that `headwidth=paper` in oneside mode uses the offsets `\the\textwidth/2-\the\paperwidth/2` as default.

---

But there are possibilities without recalculating the offsets on every page too.

If the header should have the same width as the paper set the horizontal offset of all header layers to 0pt:

```
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head}{%
    \ModifyLayer[hoffset=0pt,width=\paperwidth]{#1}%
  }{}%
}
```

Maybe you have to do the same for `plain.scrheadings`. Note that page style `plain` is only an alias for `plain.scrheadings` if `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass
  %[twoside]
  {scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline,headwidth=page]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head}{%
    \ModifyLayer[hoffset=0pt,width=\paperwidth]{#1}%
  }{}%
}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.head}{
    \ModifyLayer[hoffset=0pt,width=\paperwidth]{#1}%
  }{}%
}

\ihead{inner}\chead{center}\ohead{outer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

If only the line below of the header should be extended but not the header itself you have to modify only the `scrheadings.head.below.line` layer.

```
\documentclass
  %[twoside]
  {scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline=:page]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ModifyLayer[hoffset=0pt,width=\paperwidth]{scrheadings.head.below.line}%

\ihead{inner}\chead{center}\ohead{outer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]